# Is there any (almost surely finite) cadlag process which is not locally bounded?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

It's easy to establish that any caglad process is locally bounded. However, I doubt if the same conclusion holds for cadlag process.

Let's consider a cadlag process $X$ (say it's RCLL for all $\omega$ for simplicity). Naturally, I think of the stopping times $T_n = \inf\{t:|X_t|>n\}$. It's easy to tell that for any $\omega$ 
$$
\sup_{0 \leq s < T_n(\omega)} |X_s(\omega)| \leq n 
$$
But we don't know if the (absolute) jump size at $T_n(\omega)$ is too large to keep $X(\omega)$ bounded by $n$. Indeed my doubt results from this concern.

Then I start to think about counterexample. What I have in mind is such a "weird" process:
$$
X_t(\omega) = \begin{cases}
0, t<1\\
J(\omega), t \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
where $J$ is a random variable such that $P(J = 0) = P(J = \infty) = \frac 12$. It seems that $X$ cannot be localized to be bounded. But I don't fancy this example: as $X$ is deliberately allowed to take $\infty$. Whether or not it can be considered as "cadlag", it doesn't seem to be a good example.

So my question is: is there any example in which $X$ is cadlag, almost surely finite (given $\omega$, $X_{t}(\omega)$ is finite for all $t<\infty$), yet not locally bounded?

Comment: "It's easy to establish that any caglad process is locally bounded." << Probably you mean "continuous process"....? And could you please clarify what you mean by "locally bounded"?

Comment: @saz Here I mean "caglad" process (LCRL process). I mean by "locally bounded" the following process: say we have $X$. If there is a sequence of stopping times $\{T_n\}$ which localizes $X$ and for any $n$, there exists a constant $C_n$ such that $|X^{T_n}_t(\omega)| \leq C_n$ for any $t$ and $\omega$, $X$ is said to be locally bounded.

Comment: Ah sory, I missed the subtile difference between  cadlag and caglad.